# How to find out which app yum installs?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, fedora-15

I want to install screen and i think i could do

```
yum install screen
```

but i thought i could be smart and run a search first

```
yum search all screen
```

and here is the problem, this results in a huge list, so what will `yum install screen` do? Will install the one i want or wil it prompt me to install all?

dont want to mess up my setup :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will install the latest package with the name of "screen". Try `yum list screen`.

Comment: nice, one result :D

Answer (score 2):

Just check with

```
yum info screen
```

what you are really installing. It will give you a summary and a description of that package.

Answer (score 0):

Also, unless you invoke it as `yum -y install`, yum will always prompt you for confirmation before executing an operation. So, when you run `yum install screen`, it'll resolve your request, determine the list of packages to be installed/upgraded/whatever, then show you that list (along with the size of the download required) and ask `Is this ok [y/N]:` before proceeding.

It's very safe to just "try stuff" with yum.